# Method reference and chained predicate

Tags: java, java-8, predicate, java-stream, method-reference

I'm trying to compactify my code with method references. Here is a line that I'm trying to improve:

```
assertThat("only true & false strings allowed",
        records.stream().map(Record::getType)
        .allMatch(s -> "true".equals(s) || "false".equals(s)));
```

With method reference it could be much nicer:

```
assertThat("only true & false strings allowed",
       records.stream().map(Record::getType).allMatch("true"::equals));
```

But can I anyhow add "false" to predicate?

Comment: There was a [discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-May/033137.html) on core-libs-dev about adding `Predicate.of`.  If that happens, we'll be able to write `.allMatch(Predicate.of("true"::equals).or("false"::equals))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method in the `String` class or in the JDK that I know of that is equivalent to your `Predicate`. You can make a custom one

```
public static boolean match(String arg) {
    return "true".equals(arg) || "false".equals(arg);
}
```

and use it

```
assertThat("only true & false strings allowed",
   records.stream().map(Record::getType).allMatch(Example::match);
```

Or you can use a `Pattern` regular expression as a `Predicate`

```
assertThat("only true & false strings allowed",
   records.stream().map(Record::getType)
          .allMatch(Pattern.compile("^(false|true)$").asPredicate()));
```

And, as suggested by [Holger in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357274/method-reference-and-chained-predicate/30357489?noredirect=1#comment48807191_30357489), you could use

```
.allMatch(Arrays.asList("true", "false")::contains)
```

or something similar created from a `Set`.

Comment: Note that `Pattern.predicate` uses `find` rather than `matches`. Therefore you need `^(false|true)$` as pattern to achieve *matches* semantics.

Comment: And a solution which also works with non-`String` elements is `.allMatch(Arrays.asList("true", "false")::contains)` (though this should be used with a small number of elements only).

Answer (score 0):

You can chain `Predicates` together using `Predicate.and()` and `Predicate.or()` but first you have to coerce your method reference to a predicate

```
Predicate<String> trueTest = "true"::equals;
```

you can then either do the chaining inside your match

```
records.stream().map(Record::getType).allMatch( trueTest.or("false"::equals));
```

or create a Predicate outside the stream

```
Predicate<String> trueTest = "true"::equals;
Predicate<String> trueOrFalseTest = trueTest.or("false"::equals);


records.stream().map(Record::getType).allMatch( trueOrFalseTest );
```

Eitherway, I don't find either one to be more legible than your original code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a one-liner, but you could use the `.or()` method on `Predicate`:

```
Predicate<String> isTrue = "true"::equals;
Predicate<String> isFalse = "false"::equals;

assertThat("only true & false strings allowed",
   records.stream().map(Record::getType).allMatch(isTrue.or(isFalse)))
```